# Knet Does not Return Track ID for specific cgn

Tags: php, payment-gateway

I am using KNET payment with 2 different CGN files. Using some PHP code, one of the files returns the right track ID as expected. Using the other CGN file does not return any data. In both cases the ID goes to regular KNET process so the CGN file is correct. Does anyone have an idea why KNET does not return the right track ID?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this was an SSL certificate issue .after re-installing it  ,everything gone fine . thanks